# Who will be the Noblesse after the current one dies?

Tags: noblesse

When Kadis Etzamal di Raizel dies, who will take his position? I haven't found references for the Noblesse before Rai nor who will be his successor. Isn't there any information available?

Comment: afaik, this has not been answered in the source material, yet.

Comment: I am asking the same question myself. There are already loads of lords before the previous lord, however no mention on the previous noblesse. If there's none.. WOW.. Rai is pretty damn old!

Comment: @marcdkun19 Loads? We've only seen two so far, and I don't remember a reference to previous Lords.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by Frankenstein before, there is only one Noblesse. Also during the entire manga up till today (2016-04-15), Noblesse is always mentioned as "the" Noblesse, never "a" Noblesse like is the case with Lord. For example, in chapter 389 where Raskreia was mentioned as "a Lord". This means that there is and was only one Noblesse, and that would be Rai.

Therefore, we can't possibly tell who will be called as "the Noblesse" suppose that Rai dies, since we currently has no information on the succession pattern of the "Noblesse" title like we had on the "Lord" title.

Answer (score 1):

So I think this might answer a lot of questions. I guess its only one being and after his death will be the end of Noblesse. No one can take his place

"The True Noblesse is a title given to only one person and not the entire race as a whole."

[Source Noblesse:wikia](http://noblesse.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Nobles)

Comment: true, as of now, there has been no indication about how this works. Certainly its a title but at the same time, what about his power. He is stronger than any other Noble, so when he dies, does a new one obtain that power, or is it just gone forever, which brings up how did he get so strong in the first place if that is the case.

Comment: I have that question too. But now in the recent episodes, Rai's brother is shown who was fighting for blood stone. What do you think about him?? If there was a brother for Rai, how has he been THE NOBLESSE